# How can we stop GitHub from emailing too many people too much?

Tags: github

I recently joined a research team that uses R and Git/GitHub. The team includes 4 full-time R programmers and 10 social scientists who only run simple analyses.

I was told by one of the more experienced programmers on the project that they haven't found a way to use many of GitHub's tools for collaboration (bug reports, to-do lists, code comments, etc.) because they generate emails to everyone who is a contributor to the repo every time.

This is incredibly puzzling to me, so I'd love to hear from someone that there are ways to adjust the email settings. I'd expect there would be multiple ways, so that individuals could opt-in or opt-out of certain emails, and also so contributors could explicitly choose whether certain people get certain emails or not.

Is it possible to adjust these settings?

Answer (score 2):

To disable emailing click the tool sign at the top right. Then click "Notification centre" Here a user can change what they receive emails and notifications on the site for.

Comment: thanks, that's a good start... I'm also interested in any ways that  the more competent members could change the defaults, or specify things for different users

Comment: @MichaelBishop As far as I know with githubs default interface that isn't possible. It has to be set by the user, and only what is on that page can be changed. I suppose you could create some kind of wrapper using the github API, but this may be more work than is worth it.